# Put comma in txt file using file handling function

Tags: php, file-handling

here is my code

```
<?php

  $filename =  'names.txt';
  $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
  fwrite($file, implode(", ", $filename));

?>
```

my names.txt file data is like this

```
saad
Alex
Ashmil
Shumail
Fredrik
```

all i want that to put a qoma after each name except the last one. . but i recieve an error of 'wrong argument passed to implode function'..  tell me what should i do now ?

Expected `output` should be

`saad, Alex, Ashmil, Shumail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also try this one.
it working ......

```
<?php

$file = 'names.txt';
$array = file($file); // Creates an array of each line
$array = array_slice($array,0,-1); // Pops the last element of an array
$string = implode(',', $array); // Implode
file_put_contents($file, str_replace("\n","",$string));


?>
```

Comment: @stano i checked and put my own answer as well as answer to the question. i put which actually worked for me as per my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:)

```
<?php
$filename =  'names.txt';
$file_read = fopen($filename, 'r');
$content = fread($file_read, filesize($filename));
$content = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $content));
$pieces = explode(" ", $content);
$file_write = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($file_write, implode(", ", $pieces));
fclose($file_read);
fclose($file_write);?>
```

Comment: why ? I saw that we cant' read and write at the same time using "fwrite". so I used my own way by creating two file handlers !

Comment: Because instead of writing so many lines of code using regex where it is not needed, I can do it with small command like this: `sed '{:q;N;s/\n/, /g;t q}' in_file`

Comment: @zps215 who told you that you can't read and write with one handler o_o ? Take a look [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) under "mode".

Comment: @HamZa ya I know that , but here we have to first read the file then update the file. so If I use 'r+' mode then after fread file pointer would be at the last line and now if I do fwrite then it will append to the file..
using 'w'/'w+' we cant read first! so they are of no use.

Comment: @saad first you modify your 'names.txt' to original in which there are new lines afer every word, because it would be overwritten after so much of execution

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me :)

```
    <?php

        $file = 'names.txt';
        $array = file($file); // Creates an array of each line
        $array = array_slice($array,0,-1); // Pops the last element of an array
        $string = implode(','.PHP_EOL, $array); // Implode
        file_put_contents($file, str_replace("\n","",$string));   
?>
```

and gave me my expected output ..

Thanks @hamza, @Vivek and every one else ..

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$file = 'names.txt';
$array = file($file); // Creates an array of each line
array_pop($array); // Remove the last value of the array
$string = implode(', ', $array); // Implode
file_put_contents($file, $string); // Write to file
```

Comment: it worked but it went out like this

saad
, Alex
, Ashmel 
, etc
, etc

Comment: @saad You want to preserve the newlines ?

Comment: @saad take a look at my edit, added [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol).

Comment: @saad Ok, edit your question and show the expected output otherwise it will be a guess game.

Comment: @HamZa, if he has a lot of data `file()` will eat all his RAM (in case CLI).

Comment: @RomanNewaza never heard about that ... But to be honest one should use a database for storing big data.

Comment: @HamZa, read regarding `file()` - it reads entire file into an array so it might kill a server. About Database - it depends on use cases.

Comment: @HamZa, I would not use PHP for it, but GNU Tools like `sed` or `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
$file = 'names.txt';
$array = file($file); // Creates an array of each line
$array = array_slice($array,0,-1); // Pops the last element of an array
$string = implode(','.PHP_EOL, $array); // Implode
file_put_contents($file, str_replace(PHP_EOL,"",$string));
```

Output:-

```
saad, Alex, Ashmil, Shumail
```

Comment: lolz you copied my answer and then used `str_replace()` to replace the newlines ? You could just remove PHP_EOL in the implode part ...

Comment: It will not work. Just try it. Its not about copying but providing the right solution. :)

Comment: lolz, the solution I provided was "right" in the first place. The OP just didn't show what he exactly wanted. Now it's clear that he wants to get ride of the last value. So edit again, copy my answer, enjoy !

Comment: lol.. The OP already told that "he don't want to preserve newlines" a long time back. I copied your code because your code was partially correct and a little modification was required in your code. That's what i did.  Btw, i don't need to copy your edited code because that doesn't work as per the requirement of OP.

Comment: Please go take a look at my edit history. What I want to point out is just that you're now adding newlines, and then removing them. That doesn't make sense, just don't add them in the first place (like I did in one of my edits).

Comment: @HamZa I checked your code. It is appending new lines in the text files.

Comment: Output of your code is :- 
saad (NEWLINE)
,Alex (NL)
,Ashmil (NL)
,Shumail

Comment: You're not checking good enough, take a look at my first [post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16831610/1)

Comment: You said "What I want to point out is just that you're now adding newlines, and then removing them. That doesn't make sense, just don't add them in the first place"    I completely agree with you. I tried removing PHP_EOL from the implode working but its not working. Its appending new lines. Can you tell why ?

Comment: Check this :-  $string = implode(',', $array); // Implode
var_dump($string);